# jQuery .load() keep requesting page indefinitely

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a checkbox where when it's clicked, .load() will be called. The requested page loads just fine except that jQuery keeps requesting page over and over again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
          $('#we').click(function() {
            $('#we_div').load('/form_url');
          });
        });
</script>
<div id="we_div" style="float:right;"><input type="checkbox" id="we"  /><label for="we">Some dummy text here.</label></div>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Try to separate the checkbox and the `div` where you load the page into. Any luck?

Comment: and it IS click you have, and not mouseover which DOES load over and over - and there is nothing else clicking the label?

Comment: You mean the `div` contents keep reloading? Or how can you tell the page is being requested?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it's click not mouseover

@Shadow Wizard I can tell the page is being requested from firebug. A new `GET` request is immediately sent after another one has been completed.

Comment: What version of jQuery and do you only have ONE jQuery in the page also AFTER the load - i.e. no library and no document.ready in the /form_url

Comment: @Kemal try loading a specific page e.g. `.load("/form_url/default.php");` - any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shef gave the idea. Try this safer method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
          $('#we').click(function() {
            $('#we_div').load('/form_url',function() {
               $('#chk_span').hide();
            });
          });
        });
</script>
<div style="float:right;"><div id="we_div"></div><span id="chk_span"><input type="checkbox" id="we"  /><label for="we">Some dummy text here.</label></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps /form_url also contain this script to load /form_url.

Comment: No, that's not it. I can load `/form_url` and the page loads just fine. I can also see in firebug that a new `GET` request is sent immediately after another one has been completed.